# Enable REPL power user mode (:power) from script

Tags: scala, interpreter, read-eval-print-loop

I am trying to dynamically interpret a string as a command in Scala. For this, from what I understand, I need to call `intp.interpret("string")` (where `intp` stands for the current interpreter and `string` for my command) while being in power mode, right?

However, my problem is that I want to do that from inside a script. Thus, I am looking for a way to switch to power user mode from inside a script, and then call intp.interpret.

Is there any way to do this switching from inside a script file?

Comment: Actually I found an ugly solution: You can write `:power` in a file (let's call it `init`) and then run scala interpreter alone. Then, do  `:load init` (which will switch you to power mode) and then from the same prompt `:load program` to execute the program that wants to interpret the string. The `intp` variable should now be visible. However, I would welcome more pretty solutions :-)

Answer (score 4):

If you're invoking the REPL from a bash script or somesuch then you can enable `:power` mode immediately via the `scala.repl.power` system property,

```
miles@lewis$ scala -Dscala.repl.power
Welcome to Scala version 2.9.2 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.7.0_05)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala>
[info] compiler init time: 2.186 s.

scala>
** Power User mode enabled - BEEP BOOP SPIZ **
** :phase has been set to 'typer'.          **
** scala.tools.nsc._ has been imported      **
** global._ and definitions._ also imported **
** Try  :help,  vals.<tab>,  power.<tab>    **

scala> 
[info] total init time: 5.105 s.

scala>
```

Comment: Nope. Tried that but it doesn't work (with 2.9.2 version as well in my machine). If you run scala -Dscala.repl.power then it will work (there is some delay between the loading of the interpreter and the enabling of power mode though), however if you run scala -Dscala.repl.power scriptfile then it does not. The interpreter complains that value intp is not found.

Comment: Any way to also automate `vals.isettings.maxPrintString = Int.MaxValue` while we are at it?